# Trouble restoring a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm brand-new to MonogoDB having never used it before, and am needing to do some Power BI analysis with the data inside it.

I've installed MongoDB on my computer, and been supplied with 188 WT files.

[image]

[image]

I've tried this statement:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="C:\mongodb\data"
```

which returns:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand :
@(shell):1:0
```

This next two statements:

```
mongorestore -d test "C:\mongodb\data"
mongorestore --gzip --archive=C:\temp\restore-5f6121eed900114d.tar.gz --db test
```

returns this:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand :
@(shell):1:0
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is "188 WT files" and what you did to them?

Comment: I haven't done anything to them, it's just what the sysadmin sent me saying this is what makes up the MongoDB database.  Is that wrong?

Comment: It depends what they are and where did you save them. You are missing essential steps in your story. Did you manage to install mongodb? mongorestore requires a running instance to restore database into.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I have installed MonogoDB and there's an instance running.

Comment: Fair enough. the `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="C:\mongodb\data"` was a bit confusing as the command starts the database. If I get your screenshot you installed the database as a service, disabled authentication and can connect to it with `mongo` command. Is it about right?

Comment: For the `mongorestore --gzip --archive=...` command to work the archive must be created with `mongodump --gzip --archive=...` command. Could you also confirm it is the case.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for steering me in the right direction. I've just passed a screenshot in my original post. Seems like I can't even connect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221840/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-philip).